# Rails 7, trying to exclude applicants from a list of projects using joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a **Project** model ...

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :applicants, dependent: :destroy
end
```

... a **User** model ...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :applicants, dependent: :destroy
end
```

... and an **Applicant** model to connect them in a many-to-many.

```
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I will be doing other things with **Applicant**, so prefer to keep this structure. I am also using Devise for **Users**.

My issue is this. I am trying to return a list of **Projects** where two conditions happen.

1. The list of Projects exclude the current users own projects. This was achieved with query:

> @sugested_projects = Project.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)

2. Then I want to exclude any Projects from this list, where the User has not become an Applicant. I can find where the User **has** applied with the following:

> Project.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).joins(:applicants).where(applicants: { user_id: current_user.id })

But I can't seem to be able to find where the User **has not** applied. I tried this for example, but it doesn't work:

> Project.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).joins(:applicants).where.not(applicants: { user_id: current_user.id })

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: first condition `Project.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)` suggests Project has a user_id field, so Project belongs_to :user. But this is not shown in your Project class definition. What is the relation between project and user?

Comment: @LesNightingill they have a one to many relationship. I took out the belongs_to and has_many from their model records to make it simpler in the above example

Comment: I have added the User and Project relations back in now, in case somebody needs to review this question and answer in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a subquery that rejects all projects with an `id` that the `current_user` has an `applicant` for:

```
Project
  .where.not(user: current_user)
  .where.not(id: current_user.applicants.select(:project_id))
```

Comment: Didn't realise that I could run a select method within a query like this. Thank you for your solution. It works well.